# Prerequisites for Classical Mechanics by V.I. Arnold

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, hamiltonian-formalism, education

I have been dealing with the concepts of physics and mathematics for a long time now. I am currently interested in understanding the concepts of Classical Mechanics at a deeper level, dealing with Lagrangian and Hamiltonian formalisms. Recently, a friend suggested a book on Classical Mechanics by V.I. Arnold. I am not sure if I have the prerequisites to start understanding the concepts in the book. Let me go ahead and state what I understand well so far. Classical Mechanics at the level of Kleppner and Kolenkow, Calculus at the level of G.B. Thomas, Linear Algebra, Concepts of physics at the level of University Physics and high school mathematics.

This course on Classical Mechanics is to be taken by me along with Differential equations (beyond what Thomas offers), Electrodynamics by Griffith and Complex analysis. I am skeptical about my current understanding being enough to start reading the book by Arnold.

Comment: I seem to remember Laudau wrote a book on mechanics and it's a free pdf on the web, but sorry  I can't remember the level. Arnold takes a dim view of mathematical jargon, if that's any encouragment. I think you might have to bite the bullet here.

Comment: And you have read Goldstein? That would be standard after what you have read, also a pdf but my phone just won't carry the link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_Mechanics_(Goldstein_book) apologies if you have read it, it's excellent

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/159061/2451 and links therein.

Comment: You can start if you have some mathematical maturity.