# Mathematical prerequisites for classical (Lagrangian and Hamiltonian) mechanics

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, hamiltonian-formalism, education

I have just discovered the ideas of Lagrangian and Hamiltonian formulation of mechanics. I wish to self-study further.

I (believe I) grasp the very basic idea that both approaches are based on the energy of the system; Lagrangian the difference between kinetic and potential energy, Hamiltonian the total energy of the system.

I understand a Newtonian force-based approached to kinematics and mechanics of single particles or simple regular laminas. I understand simple energy analysis of systems where a force approach would be too complex.

I have basic calculus skills - up to college / university entrance e.g. integration of a single variable by parts and solving simple, single variable, first-order differential equations.

When I look at the mathematical formulation for a very simple system it seems to me the approach needs to be :

1. Define the Lagrangian for the system
2. Solve the resulting integral

I am having difficulty with both those steps. I think the greatest barrier is understanding the integral expression with partial derivatives. For example, what on earth does the time derivative of the partial derivative of $L$ with respect to velocity, $\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x} })$, mean (mathematically)?

So apart from (I guess) partial differentiation, what other mathematical knowledge and skills do I need to make a start on Lagrangian and Hamiltonian mechanics?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/159061/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Thanks for the link